# How to set <a title=""> for erb?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hover

I'm trying to get an erb link to display some text when a mouse is hovered over it. `<a title="hover">text</a>` works on normal text, but I can't get it to work on a link. Here's what I tried, which does nothing:

```
<a title="hover"> <%= link_to "All", "all/allthings" %> </a>
```

Am I going to have to resort to using javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to "All", "all/allthings", title: 'hover' %>
```

More information on: [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the link in a div tag with the desired title in it you will achieve the result you are looking for!

```
<div title="hover"><a href="#">link to the place</a></div>
```

Comment: That'll also probably butcher the formatting because `<div>` is a block element. The HTML might even be invalid depending on the context.

Comment: Then you can use a span tag if you need it inline, right?